# javascript and php security

Tags: javascript, php

I am wondering about "injection", including javascript injection (I don't understand its rules).

If I have  javascript function that makes an AJAX request to find out the permission level of a user, and I then check that level with an if statement to assign power, is that vulnerable?

Javascript

```
function checkPermission(){
  $.post('user.php', userId, function(data){
     return data.permission;
  });
}

var = permission = checkPermission();

     if (permission === 2){
        // User has admin powers
     }
```

Can someone read this in the code and simply change the variable "permission" to 2 and thus have admin access?

Thanks.

Comment: Open your page in *Firefox*, launch *Firebug* and go to *Script* console and type `permission=2;` after checking for permission and there you go :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's vulnerable because the user could change the userID value through their browser since javascript is run client-side.

You shouldn't rely on client side data for something like this. You'll at lease want to authenticate the user server side when they log in, and then create a session to save their userID and such. This way you can you can rely on the server-side session data, which the user won't be able to manipulate.

Edit:

Also, in your example, the user could change the value of the permission variable too. Again, no validation checks should be left up to client side code.

Comment: So it would be safe to, once the user logs in, simply store their permission ID in a PHP session variable and leave it as that - no need to check permissions again until next login.

Comment: That would be the simplest way to set it up, but you would want to check the permission with every page load. Every time the user tries to access anything that should be restricted, you should be checking the session to be sure that they're validated. On site pages, you can check first thing, and redirect them to the login page if they're not logged in, and for ajax calls you can return an error or something, so long as you're always checking.

Comment: Also, if you're going to use cookies instead of a session, be sure not to trust client side data there too. So if you need to authenticate the user, you could store a cookie with their user ID, and a cookie with a randomly generated token just for their login. You'd then store the token in a database to referance against their user ID, this way if someone changes their user ID in the cookie, their token will not match the token in your database for the user ID they've set and they will be denied access.